# Can I put an if, elsif and else into set of one liners?

Tags: perl, if-statement

(using Perl) I have a set of statements:

```
if(@good_car) {
   $goodC = 1;
}
elsif (@notbad_car) {
   $okayC = 1;
}
else {
   $badC = 1;
}
```

I was wondering if I could do something like:

```
$goodC = 1 if (@good_car),
elsif (@notbad_car) $okayC = 1 else $badC = 1;
```

I can't imagine this working really because of the elsif, but it would be nice to shorten it down a bit :) Any hints would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@good_car ? ($goodC = 1) : @notbad_car ? ($okay = 1) : ($bad = 1);
```

Comment: It's definitely shorter, but I think the double ternary is noticeably harder to read than an `if/elsif/else`.

Comment: It isnt as visually clear to read perhaps, but I understand it and have commented it so all is good :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `else` that works with the statement-modifier form of `if`.

I would just change the indentation:

```
if    (@good_car)   { $goodC = 1 }
elsif (@notbad_car) { $okayC = 1 }
else                { $badC  = 1 }
```